# Dynamically change the log level in winston

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

How can I dynamically change the log level in winston, reflecting the level change in multiple files?

I have two js files, and I am including the logger in both files. If I change the level of the logger in index.js, the change is not reflected in readfile.js

Here is my code:

**winston_logger.js**

```
var winston = require('winston');
var logger;
module.exports.init = function (logLevel) {
      logger = new(winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
            new(winston.transports.Console)({
                level: logLevel
            })
        ],
        exitOnError: false
    });
}

module.exports.getLogger = function (config) {
    if (!module.exports.logger) {
        exports.init('info')
    }
    return logger;
}

module.exports.debugLevel = function(){
  logger.transports.console.level = 'debug'
}
```

**Index.js**

```
var  readFile = require('./readFile')
var winston = require('./winston_logger')
var log = winston.getLogger()
log.info("info message" );

/*Here Im changing the log level as debug*/
winston.debugLevel ();

setTimeout(function(){
    readFile(function(){})
}, 5000)
```

**readfile.js**

```
var  readFile = require('./readFile')
var winston = require('./winston_logger')
var log = winston.getLogger()
log.info("info message" );

/*Here Im changing the log level as debug*/
winston.debugLevel ();

setTimeout(function(){
    readFile(function(){})
}, 5000)
```

Do not mark this question as a duplicate issue. [These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427982/dynamically-change-log-level-in-winston) answers have not been helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

In readfile.js import winston_logger the same way you import it in index.js

Comment: @Deva Can you show us how you fixed it? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**winston_logger.js**

```
   var winston = require('winston');
    winston.configure({
        transports: [
          new (winston.transports.Console)({ timestamp: true, json : false , colorize: true}),
          new (winston.transports.File)({filename: './somefile.log' , json : true, timestamp: true })
        ]
     });

module.exports = winston;
```

I can able to change the log level from anywhere. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given this package.json:

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "commander": "11.0.0",
    "winston": "3.9.0"
  }
}
```

this program illustrates how to adjust the logging level:

```js
import { Command } from 'commander';
import winston from 'winston';

const log = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
  ],
});

async function main(args) {
  const cmdLineOpt = new Command()
    .option('-v, --verbose', 'Print more')
    .option('-q, --quiet', 'Print less')
    .parse(args).opts();

  if (cmdLineOpt.verbose) {
    log.level = 'debug';
  }
  else if (cmdLineOpt.quiet) {
    log.level = 'warn';
  }
  else {
    log.level = 'info';
  }

  log.info('This is an information message');
  log.warn('This is a warning');
  log.debug('This is debugging information');
}

(async () => main(process.argv))();
```